# Socket.IO server to server connection doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I wrote a simple test case.

```
const socketioclient = require("socket.io-client");
const io = require("socket.io");

const server = io.listen(process.env.PORT);

server.on("connection", (client) => {
    console.log("[SERVER] Client connected!");
    client.emit("chat", "Bye!");
    client.on("bye", () => {
        console.log("[SERVER] Client goodbye'd us.");
        client.disconnect();
    })
});

const client = socketioclient("localhost:" + process.env.PORT);
client.once("connect", () => {
    console.log("[CLIENT] Connected to remote server, identificating.")
    this.sendIdentification();
});
client.on("chat", (msg) => {
    console.log("[CLIENT] Server sends message:", msg);
    if (msg.toLowerCase().indexOf("bye") != -1) {
        client.emit("bye");
    }
});
client.on("disconnected", () => {
    console.log("[CLIENT] Disconnected.");
})
client.on("error", () => {
    console.error("[CLIENT] Socket IO connection error.")
});
```

If you run it, nothing happens. Client does not connect to the server at all.

Comment: are you sure that `const client` is able to activate *after* `const server` AND `server.on` ? It sounds like a race condition to me

Comment: I'm pretty sure the javascript code executes from top to bottom. Executing the client part after timeout did not help.

Comment: I'm positive that javascript, and node, code is `async` unless specified otherwise - which is considered bad practice.

Comment: @Derek Yeah, but not every line of code is async. In the code example, server is defined before client. Events are also pushed to event queue in the order they are emitted, which means server starts listening before client starts connecting. All of that is irrelevent though - as I said, delaying the client's code does not have any effect.

Comment: Not if client ends up connecting before server does. `io.listen` is non-blocking